# How does Fate/Kaleid Liner Prisma connect to the Fate universe?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-kaleid-liner-prisma-illya

I want to know how this anime is connected to the Fate universe. I see Rin in a few trailers of the show. Also is it up to expectations with Fate/Stay Night and Fate/Zero?

Comment: From my understanding the premise was that Irisviel and Kiritsugu stopped the Holy Grail War from occurring so Ilya's purpose as the White Grail Vessel was never fulfilled. however i also read somewhere that Irisviel and Kiritsugu stopped the first war which which can't be correct because they participated in the forth war in Fate/Zero

Comment: However i do know that the Kaleid Ruby and Sapphire were made by Kischur Zelretch Schweinorg (in Fate/Kaleid) and Zelretch has the Second Magic which is the Operation of Parallel Worlds including alternate timelines. as such the Zelretch we see in it is probably the same one who helped Rin out at the end of Heaven's Feel in Fate/Stay Night, oversaw the start of the ritual that became the Holy Grail Wars, defeated Brunestud of the Crimson Moon and met a very young Alcuied

Comment: Kaleid Ruby was also created in Fate/Hollow Ataraxia by Rin which i recall reading was made to use the same principles of the Jewel Sword, an implentation of the Second Magic, and when it takes over Rin she became a Magical Girl which could be drawing the Magical Girl Rin from Fate/Kaleid

Comment: >what if we took a serious VN...
>then, what if we took some random, unimportant side character
>and then, what if we made her, and all her irrelevant friends lesbians?
>prisma illya

Comment: @Euphoric you say that as if it's a bad thing

Comment: Does it really have to be? It is not uncommon to create [spin-off](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Spinoff) while [retooling](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Retool) the characters and settings. Instead, you should be asking why did creators create the spin-off? Was there some interesting theme to be explored? Story to be told? Or do they do it just to cash in on the popularity of the franchise or character while changing it to sell even better? I leave the final decision to you.

Answer (score 1):

Fate/kaleid liner PRISMA☆ILLYA is an alternate timeline to Fate/Stay Night

> The series takes place in Fuyuki City in an alternate timeline of Fate/stay night. Kiritsugu and Irisviel helped end the Holy Grail War ritual before it could start, sealing Ilya's memories away and allowing her to grow up as a normal girl. Shirou and Ilya live a peaceful life as brother and sister, without knowledge of magic, under the care of Sella and Leysritt, while their parents are abroad.

Source: [Fate/kaleid liner PRISMA☆ILLYA - STory - Setting (First Paragraph)](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Fate/kaleid_liner_PRISMA%E2%98%86ILLYA#)

however it may be apart of a different timeline to that in which Fate/Zero occurred because of Shirou's background

> It is unknown what happened to his biological parents, as the Great Fire had never occurred, but he was still adopted by Kiritsugu about ten years ago, similar to his Fate/stay night origins.

Source: [Shirou Emiya (Fate/kaleid - Illya's brother) - Profile - Background](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Shirou_Emiya_(Fate/kaleid))

however multiple timelines that are still connected is possible in the Nasuverse as Kischur Zelretch Schweinorg wield the Second Magic which is the Operation of Parallel worlds. he was also present when the Makiri, Tohsaka and Einzbern Family began the ritual that would later be known as the Holy Grail Wars

[image]

In the image above we can see Zelretch reading a book and Lord El-Melloi II, AKA, Waver Velvet from Fate/Zero and like Shirou how he got the title of Lord El-Melloi II in this world is unknown as it was during Fate/Zero in which Kayneth El-Melloi Archibald was killed and Waver helped restore the House's name to which his new name was award to him and where he "serves" Reines El-Melloi Archisorte

> While it was on the brink of collapse, Waver Velvet's actions helped to revive the Archibald house, and he was then named as "Lord El-Melloi II" as a form of gratitude. At the bottom of the family's hierarchy at the time, she "blamed" him for causing the situation and claimed "you better serve me for your entire life," much to the former's chagrin.

Source: [Reines El-Melloi Archisorte - Profile - Background](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Reines_El-Melloi_Archisorte)

so if Irisviel and Kiritsugu stopped the 4th War then the Archibald house wouldn't be in a state of collapse because of Kayneth's death and Shirou wouldn't have been adopted because the corrupted Holy Grail wouldn't have started the great fire which claimed his family

However some titles in the Nausverse do extend from other branches in it's history that aren't covered in other Fate titles, such as with *Fate/Apocrypha* which occurs in a separate timeline caused by the Einzbern Family summoning Ruler during the 3rd Holy Grail War instead of Avenger or in *Fate/Extra* in which a certain Magic Incident (assumed to be a premature Aylesbury Valesti) cause the world's Mana to dry up in the 1970's, years before the forth Holy Grail War in the 1990's (and thus the Greater Grail would take longer to build up Mana for the 4th war if it even occurred)

with that being said the point in the history of the Nasuverse in which could allow for the alterations to Shirou's and Waver's history in Fate/kaleid liner PRISMA☆ILLYA without the 4th war occurring is currently unknown.

NOTE: apologies for the lack on anchor links however Wikia's Ad overload has made the site impossible for me to browse with javascript enabled

Comment: would like to add that the Aylesbury Valesti is connected with the 27 Dead Apostle Ancestors and they are generally only mentioned in Tsukihime, Kagetsu Tohya and Melty Blood which are still set in the Nasuverse but don't have anything to do with the Holy Grail Wars, Masters or Servants

Comment: Also see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4FE.png

Comment: @кяαzєя can you site the Volume/Chapter and Page Number for that?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cbsrJ.jpg)  is one of the author afterword from the *Zwei* compiled volumes I believe. However, I'm not sure witch volume specificakky it's from.